# Cannot execute binary file with bash command

Tags: bash, binaryfiles

I want to run a `cpp` executable from my git for windows bash. I do not understand why I can run it with `./Main`  but I can't run it with `bash Main` or `bash Main.exe`. In the latter cases, I'm getting an error:

> cannot execute binary file

**main.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
std::cout<<"Hello World";
return 0;
}
```

**script.sh**

```
 echo "Hello from Bash script.."
    echo "Hostname:${1}"
    echo "Port:${2}"
    echo "Listing contents:"
    ls -a
    echo "Launching cpp executable:"
    path=$(pwd)
    echo "Current path:${path}"
    bash "${path}/Main"
```

To compile the C++ code, I'm using: `g++ -o Main main.cpp`.

What is the problem? Can someone explain please?

Comment: Where are you compiling your `.cpp` ?

Comment: I updated my post .

Comment: I'm not sure there's much more to say than what `bash` already told you : it can't execute binary files.

Comment: Well is there any difference between `bash executableFileName` and `./executableFileName` ?

Comment: of course. When you say `bash filename` you're telling bash to execute the **shell commands** found in the file: it is expected to be a text file containing a shell script.

Comment: you might want `bash -c executableFile` which spawns a bash shell to run the specified command, but you still need to provide the path to it, just like `./executableFile`

Comment: For more details: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash -- "If arguments remain after option processing, and neither the -c nor the -s option has been supplied, the first argument is assumed to be the name of a file containing shell commands"

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `bash` on the last line of your script:

```
"${path}/Main"
```

Don't forget to make it executable.

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

It worked for me:

```
./script.sh hostname 80
Hello from Bash script..
Hostname:hostname
Port:80
Listing contents:
.       ..      Main        main.cpp    script.sh
Launching cpp executable:
Current path:/tmp/test
Hello World
```