# Batch run exe file

Tags: bash, batch-file, exe

I'm trying to make a batch file that compiles and executes the created exe file. The problem is that it's saying:

```
./main.exe: ./main.exe: cannot execute binary file
```

I've seen people saying that it's an arch type problem, but both my PC and file are 64 bit. To be precise, my PC is amd64 and the file is x86-64. Am I missing something simple here? I'm not experienced with batch files, so it could be something small.

Here is the batch file:

```bash
gcc -c lib/recipe.c -o lib/recipe.o
gcc main.c lib/recipe.o -o main
bash ./main.exe
```

Comment: To clarify, the EXE does work if I run it separately, so there is nothing with the compilation.

Comment: Add output of command `file main.exe` to your question (no comment here).

Comment: @Cyrus main.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows

Comment: Don't use the `bash` command to run things that aren't bash scripts. I *think* you just want `./main.exe` here, but your description of what's going on is confusing. Is this bash or ba**t**ch? [They're different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079180/what-is-the-difference-between-batch-and-bash-files) in many ways. Also, is this under WSL under Windows or something like that?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of ["Cannot execute binary file with bash command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52445372/cannot-execute-binary-file-with-bash-command).

Comment: @GordonDavisson it is a batch file that is run on windows directly. It is not a direct duplicate because the fix for your post is on Linux and the fix itself is slightly different on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `bash ./main.exe` is problematic: you do not want to call `bash` with `./main.exe` as argument but you want to call `./main.exe` directly.
Changing the `bash ./main.exe` to `main.exe` should do the trick.

Comment: I needed to remove ./ before the main.exe to use your solution

Comment: Good to know! I'm not familiar with Windows. But did it work properly ?

Comment: It worked like I wanted it to so yes